# Когда использовать margin и padding в CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Существуют ли правило или принцип при написании CSS, по которому следует использовать `margin` или `padding` для добавление отступов?

Comment: Хм, а это вы сами добавили дисклеймер, что вопрос является переводом, или же система сайта автоматически?

Comment: @Станислав сам добавил. Нажмите кнопку "править" и подсмотрите разметку.

Comment: Да я уже посмотрел, но все равно решил спросить, так как не пойму смысла сего действа.

Comment: @Станислав переводить хорошие вопросы-ответы - можно. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4224/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so

Надеюсь что уважаемый Vadizar сейчас ответы тоже переводит =)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, что-то не торопится :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это решает сам верстальщик. Всё упирается в дизайн. В разных CSS-фреймворках, действительно, есть правила. Но эти правила не унифицированные.

Так, используйте `padding` для отступа внутри блока, `margin` – для отсупа самого блока.

Опять же, в зависимости от шаблона (или настроения), можно вообще не использовать данные правила.

Comment: разница то понятна, а вот есть ли какие либо принципы, к примеру, для отступа блока от другого блока, у которого нет бордера и разница между внешним и внутренним откупом видна не будет. Как быть в таких случаях?

Comment: так, как вы описываете, например, работает bootstrap: в сетке бутстрапа по-умолчанию между ячейками нет маржинов, только падинги и за счёт этого достигается визуальный геп между ними.